# Django, display count of unread messages in base template

Tags: django, django-templates, facebook-messages

I am working on a project in which I have implemented messaging system like facebook where users can send messages to each other. The number of unread messages of a particular thread is also displayed on the messages page.

Now what I want is to **display the count of unread messages in the navigation bar** (which is there in base.html) each time user logs in. How to do this whenever a user logs in?

Please suggest, and I don't want to use any other app for this purpose. Thanks

Comment: are you using a user profile model ?

Comment: @karthikr : actually no

Comment: I've done something similar in the past with a view I call via ajax. You could even have the js part executed every n seconds so that it updates when a new message was received

Comment: @la_f0ka: well i think i need to do that also to keep updating page after some time, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) which can do this for you.

```
def unread_messages(user):
    return user.messages_set.filter(read=False).count()
    #replace the messages_set with the appropriate related_name, and also the filter field. (I am assuming it to be "read")

register.simple_tag(unread_messages)
```

and in the base template:

```
{% load <yourtemplatetagname> %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ request.user|unread_messages }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: its showing me the following error:
TemplateSyntaxError Invalid filter: 'unread_messages'

Comment: You might have forgotten to `{% load %}` the template tag

Comment: yes i was missing this one, this approach will help me, Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

A [simpletag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) should be the easiest solution for you. This solution worked for me and is based on the Django documentation.

Use the following folder structure within your app.

```
user_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templates/
        user_app/
            base.html
            ...
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        user_tags.py
    views.py
    ...
```

Within the `user_tags.py`

```py
from django import template
from user_app.models import Notification

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_unread_messages_count(context):
    return Notification.objects.filter(recipient=context["request"].user, read=False).count()
```

Within `base.html`

```
{% load user_tags %}

...



<a href="{% url 'messages' %}">
   Messages <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-danger">{% get_unread_messages_count %}</span>
</a>
```

Of course you need to implement your own styles and classes for your specific project. I am using the Bootstrap 5.3 [pill badges](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/badge/#pill-badges).